# View contents of Index in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, psql

I want to view the data and structure of an indexes on a table; specifically non-clustered indexes. Is it possible to use a sql query to select/view the data stored in a non-clustered index? If not are there additional psql functions that can be called to view the data and/or structure of an index?

Comment: `psql -E ....` and then `\di ...` you will get queries used by `psql` to obtain info. Try to reuse them.

Comment: The content of the index is simply: `select index_col_1, index_col_2, ... from table_name`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - am late to party - but I have interest in same. I feel the OP is asking how to view the content of an index itself.. just like we can see the content of a table. And is further interest in additional metadeta like the structure of the index like BTree or BITMap or GIN etc. If you can readdress this Q.. I will appreciate.

Comment: @Abelisto - plz see above comment.

Comment: @samshers The "content" of an index is the value of the indexed columns (or expressions). If there is an index on `column_1, column_2` then `select column_1, column_2 from the_table` will show the "content"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - i see your point. But for example if the index is a partial index then `select column_1, column_2 from the_table` will not give the index content but the table content. But that is a narrow example I just gave. For example say, in case of GIN indexes - it stores key/values of jsonb document in indexes and I am  interested in seeing those. Like what  keys or values got indexed etc. Just a dig. And also to add - what data structure the DB used internally. I understand all this may be stored in binary format, possibility, and may not be viewed by users directly.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I know is the pageinspect module. More specifically check this [section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html#PAGEINSPECT-B-TREE-FUNCS).

```
SELECT itemoffset, ctid, itemlen, nulls, vars, data, dead, htid, tids[0:2] AS some_tids
    FROM bt_page_items('tenk2_hundred', 5);
```

[image]

> This is a B-tree leaf page. All tuples that point to the table happen to be posting list tuples (all of which store a total of 100 6 byte TIDs). There is also a “high key” tuple at itemoffset number 1. ctid is used to store encoded information about each tuple in this example, though leaf page tuples often store a heap TID directly in the ctid field instead. tids is the list of TIDs stored as a posting list.